# How can I solve my app crash error?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a new Android developer, and I just released my first app but I am getting app crash reports.

This is the problem I am getting. As far as I can understand, it's saying the error generates on the 69 line of my fragment class.

```
 Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
 android.content.ComponentName.<init> (ComponentName.java:77)
 android.content.Intent.<init> (Intent.java:4913)
 com.botmad.questionme.AnswerFragmentOne.refresh (AnswerFragmentOne.java:69)
 com.botmad.questionme.AnswerFragmentOne$1.run (AnswerFragmentOne.java:60)
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
 android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
 android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

And here is my fragmentOne code

```
 public void refresh(){
    this.startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), PlayActivity.class));
    actvty.overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    actvty.finish();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    actvty = (Activity)context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

    final PlayActivity actvty = (PlayActivity) getActivity();
    actvty.soundeffect(1);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            refresh();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

The refresh function's first line is the 69 line. So that's where the error generates but I am not sure why orhow to solve this problem? I am restarting my main activity from this fragment. There is pretty much nothing else in the fragment class. Just a button that calls this refresh function on onClick.

Comment: Looks like `getContext()` is returning null in some cases.....  Where exactly do you call this `refresh()` function?

Comment: @DanielNugent i included the the part where i call the refresh function

Comment: Ok, try clicking the button and then immediately exiting the app, and see if you can reproduce the crash.....It looks like the 4 second delay, then calling `getContext()` without checking if it's null is the issue.

Comment: @DanielNugent Yes it crashed. So storing the getcontext value and calling start activity only if the returned context is not null should solve the problem right?

Comment: @DanielNugent The problem is solved. Thank you! :)